# The database doesn't have its tables generated

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Hi, I'm busy developing a Java EE app using Hibernate and Spring. I have an Article class that I've run. But no table is generated for it. No errors in the console.

Here's the Article class:

```
package com.bd.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Articlet")
public class Article {

    int id;
    String nom;
    String type;
    int qte;


    public Article() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
     @Column(name="ID")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
     @Column(name="Nom")
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }
    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }
     @Column(name="Type")
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
     @Column(name="Qunatité")
    public int getQte() {
        return qte;
    }
    public void setQte(int qte) {
        this.qte = qte;
    }




}
```

and the ArticleDao class:

```
package com.bd.dao;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;



import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.bd.entity.Article;
@Repository
@Transactional
@Configuration
public class ArticleDaoImp implements ArticleDao {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Article> getAll() {

        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Article")
                .list();
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Article getById(int articleId) {

        return (Article) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Article.class,
                articleId);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Article article) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(article);

    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Article article) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(article);

    }

}
```

And here's the hibernatedataccesscontext file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

  <!-- Auto-detect the DAOs -->
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.bd.dao"/>
 <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.bd.service"/>
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.bd.controleur"/> -->


  <context:property-placeholder location="WEB-INF/jdbc.properties"/>


    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.bd.entity.Article</value>

            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>     
                <!-- generation base donnée     <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop> -->
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="articleListeners">
      <map>
        <entry key="merge">
          <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.IdTransferringMergeArticleListener"/>
        </entry>
      </map>
    </property>
    </bean>




  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txnManager"/>

  <bean id="txnManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>

  <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

</beans>


    et jdbc.properties


database.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ccccc
database.user=root
database.password=root
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
```

The problem is that no database constructs get generated. Please help.

Comment: Je crois que vous dois parler angle ici. (forgive my french, im not a proficient speaker)

Comment: I've just submitted an edit with a translation. English is the standard language here on SO, you'd probably find only limited assistance when asking in another language. Votre problème est qu'aucune table est générée sur la base de données a partir de vos classes, correct?

Comment: hello, i trying of developer an apllication jee hibernate spring
i have a class article,
i try of generate the database but it is not generated
i have not no error in the consol

Comment: Quelqu'un va probablement demander d'ajouter le config JPA (persistence.xml) ou Hibernate. Je ne sais pas si la génération de tables est automatiquement active.

Comment: how i will on the automatic generation of the datbase??

Comment: Comment est-ce-que vous utilisez Hibernate? Avec `hibernate.cfg.xml` ou simplement avec `persistence.xml`? Simplement avoir des classes persistance ne va rien faire, faut avoir un configuration.

Comment: i used hibernate 3 without jpa, and i use the file hibernateaccessdatacontexte.xml already i added this file in the my quetion

Comment: Didn't see that. It got lumped together with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Hibernate configuration xml, make sure you have `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` set to either `update`, `create`, or `create-drop`.

Comment: i added hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto and create-drop, it same problem

Comment: please help me 
i have 2 days in this problem
please

Comment: If you're still having trouble with this, post the error you're getting, that would help (Should be in your log).